# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [514, 514, 4]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

```
X = data.iloc[:,1:-1].values

y = data.iloc[:, -1].values

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest =train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

print(f"Train Data: {xTrain.shape}, {yTrain.shape}")

print(f"Test Data: {xTest.shape}, {yTest.shape}")

forest = RandomForestClassifier()

forest.fit(xTrain, yTrain)

accuracy = forest.score(xTest, yTest)

print('The accuracy was', 100*accuracy, '% on the test data.')
```

---

I think that my code is correct, because the shape result of the split data when checked and run on the RandomForestClassifier from package scikit-learn is correct.

### But when run on RandomForestClassifier without package, forest.fit() shows an error. Has anyone been able to resolve this error?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-3353626df052> in <module>
      1 forest = RandomForestClassifier()
----> 2 forest.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
      3 
      4 accuracy = forest.score(xTest, yTest)
      5 print('The accuracy was', 100*accuracy, '% on the test data.')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [514, 514, 4]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run on RandomForestClassifier without package"? Do you have your own implementation of that method? What error is forest.fit() showing?

Comment: So scikit-learn has the RandomForestClassifier library, if I use that my code doesn't have an error. However, if I use the random forest code that I wrote myself forest.fit() shows an error like the one above.

Comment: Could you provide your random forest code?

Comment: Sure, you can check it here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1V1HPcZoRo92Lh1Gz4asvLocCw1E9V3w6?usp=share_link

Comment: Hard to say where the error is, but you do have cases where you use `is` when you should use `==` in your DecisionTreeClassifier. Try fixing those and see what happens.

Comment: The error still seems to happen in the sklearn-package, when you fit the single decision tree for the forest (it would be better to show the full error message from your colab script). Could you check that each decision tree guaranteed gets a sample? This is the error part (more details in your colab): /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(test_size, train_size, random_state, shuffle, stratify, *arrays)
   2415         raise ValueError("At least one array required as input")

Comment: OK, thanks guys for the responses. I'll try to refine the decision tree like your suggestion.